# Ruby on Rails - Google Autocomplete Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm currently trying to implement an autocomplete location field but I'm unable to figure out how to get it working.

Here is an [example](http://rjshade.com/projects/gmaps-autocomplete/) of what I'm trying to accomplish, except the map, I just need to enter a location and save the data to a model. Unfortunately the [linked repo's example](https://github.com/rjshade/gmaps-autocomplete) only shows how to use `simple_form_for`. I'm currently using `bootstrap_form_for` and can't figure out how to make it work.

Same with [gmaps-autocomplete-rails](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails) and using `semantic_form_for`.

I'm still trying to figure out where all the .js goes, and how it's setting up / working together with Rails.

Any examples or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple ..

1. First ensure that you completed these steps deffined in https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails in the **install** section(no need of Customization section for beginers)
2. Then place this in the view file

   `= simple_form_for(resource) do |f|
    = f.input :address, :input_html =>{:id => 'gmaps-input-address'}, :placeholder => 'Start typing a place name...'`

remember.. the id 'gmaps-input-address' should be present, and also provide the api key of google.

Comment: I'm not using `simple_form_for`. I'm using `bootstrap_form_for` and I'm worried that using both would add some issues.

And how do I provide the API key in that example? What file does it go into, or how does it go into the f.input field?

Comment: it may be simple_form_for, or it may be bootstrap_form_for, you can use any of them, but make sure that you have added an extra id = gmaps-input-address to that field. And for the api key, you can also do it without api key, in that case it will give a warning in console. simply add this line in the top of the view file where the input field is present
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>